# In plain English, how to descibe i/o of the TensorFlow for language modelling?

Tags: deep-learning, tensorflow, language-model

I have followed the tutorial [here](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/tutorials/recurrent/index.html#language_modeling) about language modelling using Tensorflow to create LSTM and used PTB dataset. The code is [here](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/models/rnn/ptb/ptb_word_lm.py)

I failed to understnad the exact specific input and the output of the model.

My question is: how many words do you feed to the model and how many words do you expect at the end? How the data processing happens?

For example: if I have the sentence "The quick brown fox jumps over the lazy dog.". This will be turned into vectors using word2vec. Then how are these given to the NN?